# Parsing a string into a boolean value in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, boolean

Today I was playing with PHP, and I discovered that the string values "true" and "false" are not correctly parsed to boolean in a condition, for example considering the following function:

```
function isBoolean($value) {
   if ($value) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

If I execute:

```
isBoolean("true") // Returns true
isBoolean("") // Returns false
isBoolean("false") // Returns true, instead of false
isBoolean("asd") // Returns true, instead of false
```

It only seems to work with "1" and "0" values:

```
isBoolean("1") // Returns true
isBoolean("0") // Returns false
```

Is there a native function in PHP to parse "true" and "false" strings into boolean?

Comment: In your code, `isBoolean("")` should return false.

Comment: PHP doesn't *think* about what  string says, "false" is just five characters that mean nothing. They are *something* though, so the boolean value evaluates to `true` even though to a human reader, it would seem more intuitive that it meant `FALSE`.

Answer (score 471, accepted):

There is a native PHP method of doing this which uses PHP's filter_var method:

```
$bool = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

According to [PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php):

> Returns TRUE for "1", "true", "on" and "yes". Returns FALSE otherwise.
>
> If FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE is set, FALSE is returned only for "0", "false", "off", "no", and "", and NULL is returned for all non-boolean values.

Comment: does it also lowercase the value for the comparison?

Comment: @Mobiletainment, yes - it handles any casing you can imagine for $value (false, FALSE, FalSe, etc.)

Comment: Borked testcase on my end. Used == instead of === for comparison. Will remove my earlier comment to not confuse people.

Comment: I have never seen this before. Excellent solution.

Comment: The answer caught me off guard because you have to add the flag ``FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`` to the ``filter_var()`` function and NOT replace it with ``FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN`` as I thought. This will result in the following code which did the trick for me: ```$bool = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)```

Comment: Also there is PHP's [`boolval()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.boolval.php) (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7). Depending on one's needs, `boolval()` may be better. For what I need, [`filter-var()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7) fits better. To choose between one or another, I suggest doing a test [like this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#121263).

Comment: @AntonioViniciusMenezesMedei, the problem with your answer is `boolval('false')` returns **true** - which is the opposite of what's being requested in the question. boolval is great, but it isn't the right solve for this.

Answer (score 16):

The reason is that all strings evaluate to `true` when converting them to boolean, except `"0"` and `""` (empty string).

The following function will do exactly what you want: it behaves exactly like PHP, but will also evaluates the string `"false"` as `false`:

```
function isBoolean($value) {
   if ($value && strtolower($value) !== "false") {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

The documentation explains that: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php :

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and **the string "0"**
> - an array with zero elements
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> **Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).**

Comment: @Marco - if ($value && strtolower($value) !== "faux") { if you're working in French; if ($value && strtolower($value) !== "falsch") { in german; if ($value && strtolower($value) !== "onwaar") { in dutch... you can understand why PHP doesn't have this built in as standard

Comment: "all **non-empty** strings evaluate to true when converting them to boolean, except "0"."

Answer (score 6):

In PHP only `"0"` or the empty string coerce to false; every other non-empty string coerces to true. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `FALSE`:
>
> - the empty string, and the string "0"

You need to write your own function to handle the strings `"true"` vs `"false"`. Here, I assume everything else defaults to false:

```
function isBoolean($value) {
   if ($value === "true") {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

On a side note that could easily be condensed to

```
function isBoolean($value) {
   return $value === "true";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently needed a "loose" boolean conversion function to handle strings like the ones you're asking about (among other things).  [I found a few different approaches and came up with a big set of test data to run through them](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QqWJTI).  Nothing quite fit my needs so I wrote my own:

```
function loosely_cast_to_boolean($value) {
    if(is_array($value) || $value instanceof Countable) {
        return (boolean) count($value);
    } else if(is_string($value) || is_object($value) && method_exists($value, '__toString')) {
        $value = (string) $value;
        // see http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php#108218
        // see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49510
        $filtered = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
        if(!is_null($filtered)) {
            return $filtered;
        } else {
            // "none" gets special treatment to be consistent with ini file behavior.
            // see documentation in php.ini for more information, in part it says: 
            // "An empty string can be denoted by simply not writing anything after 
            // the equal sign, or by using the None keyword".
            if(strtolower($value) === 'none') {
                $value = '';
            }
            return (boolean) $value;
        }
    } else {
        return (boolean) $value;
    }
}
```

Note that for objects which are both countable and string-castable, this will favor the count over the string value to determine truthiness.  That is, if `$object instanceof Countable` this will return `(boolean) count($object)` regardless of the value of `(string) $object`.

You can see the behavior for the test data I used as well as the results for several other functions [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QqWJTI).  It's kind of hard to skim the results from that little iframe, so you can [view the script output in a full page](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QqWJTI/5.4.0?), instead (that URL is undocumented so this might not work forever).  In case those links die some day, [I put the code up on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9kmcFe0K) as well.

The line between what "ought to be true" and what oughtn't is pretty arbitrary; the data I used is categorized based on my needs and aesthetic preferences, yours may differ.

Comment: This function works flawlessly, thank you! But your links are now 404.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this construct to morph strings into booleans, since you want `true` for most other values:

```
$str = "true";
$bool = !in_array($str, array("false", "", "0", "no", "off"));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function in PHP to parse "true" and "false" strings into boolean?

No - both are strings, and those both (as you say) evaluate to `true`. Only empty strings evaluate to `false` in PHP.

You would need to test for this manually. If at all possible, though, it would be better to work with "real" boolean values instead.

Comment: Not all strings evaluate to `true` in PHP.

Comment: Wasn't correcting, just clarifying. Saying "both are strings [and evaluate to `true`]" might give a newbie the wrong impression, especially one from another language with stricter typing rules where a string is a string and the contents don't matter when it's being converted to a boolean (like Ruby).

Comment: _"Only empty strings evaluate to false in PHP."_  But what about the non-empty string `"0"`?  Doesn't this also evaluate to `false`?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Way to safely convert to a boolean;

```
    $flag = 'true';

    if( filter_var( $flag,FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE ) !== null) {
      $flag = filter_var($flag,FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
    }

    gettype($flag); // Would Return 'Boolean'
    echo 'Val: '.$flag; // Would Output 'Val: 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your API only accepts the strings "true" or "false", 
with *everything else becoming `null`*, then try:

```php
$boolean = ['true' => true, 'false' => false][$inputString] ?? null;
```

This assumes that `$input` is not an object.
Null coalesce (`??`) was introduced in PHP 7.0.