# Can this code be used in order to validate $_GET variables?

Tags: php, get

I am building a page where GET parameters are used and i am wondering if this piece of code successfully evaluates the next conditions: **$_GET["id"]** must be an **integrer** and **$_GET["status"]** must be a **"true"** or **"false"**.

```
$rawId = $_GET["id"];
$rawStatus = $_GET["status"];

$Id = filter_var($rawId, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$Id = filter_var($Id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if (!$Id) {
    die();
}

if ($rawStatus != "true" && $rawStatus != "false") {
    die();
}
```

Comment: Also should add an isset() to check wheter these parameters are declared...

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_int and is_bool to achieve this. Make sure you are also checking if the $_GET vars are set before you do this to avoid potential notices

```
$rawId = (isset($_GET["id"]) ? $_GET["id"] : null);
$rawStatus = (isset($_GET["status"]) ? $_GET["status"] : null);

if (!is_int($rawId)) {
     //handle
}

if (!is_bool($rawStatus)) {
     //handle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` allows for `.`, `+` and `-`, which you probably don't want to include. Using `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` would be fine for regular integer checks, though keep in mind that this will return `false` for `0`. If you want your IDs to also include `0`, then you'll need to explicitly check for this:

```
$Id = filter_var($rawId, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === 0 || filter_var($rawId, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT));
```

Assuming you want `$rawStatus` to be a literal string of `true` / `false`, then the way you have it covered at the moment is probably the most optimal approach, though it sounds like you're trying to make a boolean check here. In this case, you can simply check for the **presence** of `$rawStatus`, using the lack of its presence to denote a falsy value:

```
if ($rawStatus)
```

And as you mention in your comment, you will indeed want to check that both are set with `isset()`... but you'll *also* want to check that the values are not empty. This can be done with `!empty()`.

I'd also recommend only proceeding in a know valid state, rather than calling `die()` in a known invalid state.

Putting this all together, you'll have something that looks like the following:

```
$rawId = null;

if (isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"])) {
    $rawId = $_GET["id"];
}
if (isset($_GET["status"]) && !empty($_GET["status"])) {
    $rawStatus = $_GET["status"];
}

$Id = filter_var($rawId, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === 0 || filter_var($rawId, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if ($Id && $rawStatus) {
    // Logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the type of $rawId and $rawStatus you can do it

```
is_integer($rawId); // return true if $rawId is integer
```

```
is_bool($rawStatus); // return true if $rawStatus is boolean
```

To check if $rawId has only numbers you can do it

```
is_numeric($rawId)
```

To check if $rawStatus is bool you can see this answer

[Test if string could be boolean PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272723/test-if-string-could-be-boolean-php)

If is needed to parse the values you can use **intval()** and **boolval()**