# Hide show content with Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'd like to create a form that sets a Cookie on submission, then either hide or show content on subsequent pages depending on the existence of the cookie.

I've got using the jquery.cookie.js and this code on the form:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button").on('click',function() {
            $.cookie('showcontent', true, { expires: 7 });
          });
    });
```

And this code on the subsequent pages:

CSS

```
    .contentA {
    display: none;}
```

Javascript

```
if (!$.cookie('showcontent')) {
    $( ".contentA" ).show();
    $( ".contentB" ).hide();
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="contentA">  
    <h1>Content A</h1>
</div>

<div class="contentB">  
    <h1>Content B</h1>
</div>
```

At the moment it doesn't function, so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: have you done the reverse for your if?  You set it to true but then do an if on  not true

Comment: are you loading the jquery before cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you looks at [this sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEmet) it works as it should, but since it is a cookie, [cookies are text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752442/jquery-cookie-set-value-to-boolean-true) that are stored in the users browser, so it should be like this:

```
if ($.cookie('showcontent') == 'true')
```

and make sure to load jquery before adding the cookie library

Comment: Many thanks, this and the comment above did the trick ie. add 'if not true'