# Why isn't my cookie updating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am making a dark mode for a site using a button toggle. To keep the dark mode saved when changing pages, I am using cookies. When pressing the toggle again, the dark mode is disabled but is not saving and I am not sure why.

Ps. I am new at javascript so this may be a dumb mistake.

```
if ($.cookie('darkModeOn')){
      $('html').toggleClass('dark-mode');

      $('#dark-toggle').click(function(){
      $.cookie('darkModeOn', false, { expires: 7 });
      $('html').toggleClass('dark-mode');
      });
   }
   else
   {
      $('#dark-toggle').click(function(){
      $.cookie('darkModeOn', true, { expires: 7 });
      $('html').toggleClass('dark-mode');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you press the toggle button you also want to toggle the True/False value of the cookie. Now you always either set it to True or to False depending on the first state.

Use `! $.cookie('darkModeOn')` as value to store into the cookie to automatically toggle the boolean value.

---

**EDIT**

It was indeed not working, and I found out that it was not working because of the boolean values.
The boolean values are stored as string (`"false"` and `"true"`) since `if ( "false")` gives boolean true, the if is always executed. When you use integers instead of booleans this would work, but you can also change the if to:

```
if ($.cookie('darkModeOn')=="true") //...
```

---

If you use integers it also works:

https://jsfiddle.net/6m2ydrh2/12/

```
$('#dark-toggle').click(function(){
       //this gets executed each click so we need to toggle the boolean value.
      if ($.cookie('darkModeOn')==0){
          $.cookie('darkModeOn', 1, { expires: 7 });
      }else{
          $.cookie('darkModeOn', 0, { expires: 7 });
      }
      console.log( "cookie:"+$.cookie('darkModeOn')) ;
      $('#test').toggleClass('dark-mode');
  });
  if ($.cookie('darkModeOn')){
       //this is only executed on load
      $('#test').toggleClass('dark-mode');
  }
```

See also this post: [jquery cookie set value to boolean true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752442/jquery-cookie-set-value-to-boolean-true).
The boolean values are stored as string and therefor causing problems.

Comment: hmm, that didn't seem to work for me. Same problem. Thank you though!

Comment: @LoganManuel I found out why it indeed was not working. Check my updated answer.