# Toggle cookie true false magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, cookies

Im using jquery cookie to drop a cookie when the user presses a button on my mage store to show and hide vat prices.

My current js looks like so:

```
$j('.nav-customer-vat a').click(function(){

    $j(this).text($j(this).text() == 'Show VAT' ? 'Hide VAT' : 'Show VAT');
    $j(this).toggleClass('active');

    if($j(this).text() == 'Show VAT'){
        console.log('show');
        $j.cookie("showVat", false, { path: '/' });     
    } else if($j(this).text() == 'Hide VAT'){
        $j.cookie('showVat', true)
        console.log('hide');
    } 
}
```

Im then using on the frontend the following magento cookie getModel to test if the cookie is true or false:

```
<?php  $cookie = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('showVat'); ?>
        <?php if($cookie){ ?>
        <a href="#" class="display-vat"><?php echo $this->__('Hide VAT'); ?></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="#" class="display-vat"><?php echo $this->__('Show VAT'); ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
```

However this only seems to work once over then it will always return false on every click, I can't seem to figure why this is. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because cookies are saved as string. And the string *"false"* evaluates as *true*. So you need to set actual string values and compare those.

More information in this post: [jquery cookie set value to boolean true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752442/jquery-cookie-set-value-to-boolean-true)

Comment: So just to clarify Aximus is right above, what i did to change this is the following:  Altered the cookie to: $j.cookie('showVat', 'enabled', { path: '/' });
 if($j(this).text() == 'Show VAT'){ $j.cookie("showVat", 'disable', { path: '/' });  } '   Then in php <?php if($cookie == 'enabled' ?> Thanks.