# Converting String true/false to interger value

Tags: php

I'm getting true or false  from query string i don't have access to change this `www.example.com?is_test=true`

But in backend for database i'm excepting integer like 0,1

To achieve this i'm trying like this

```
(int) (boolean) 'true' //gives 1
(int) (boolean) 'false' //gives 1 but i need 0 here
```

Event i tried

```
$test = "false";
$bool = settype($test, 'boolean'); //it was giving true

(int) $bool also gives 1
```

i'm not sure there might be some other better php function to achieve this? 
Or any better way to this please suggest

Yah ternary operator is one best option But is there any other options for conversion

Comment: Please check another same requirement and solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775294/parsing-a-string-into-a-boolean-value-in-php

Comment: `intval($_GET['is_test'] === 'true')`

Comment: Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10645030/4246973

Answer (score 2):

PHP can't read your strings. You'll have to use some kind of if-else construction:

```
if ($GET['is_test'] === 'false') {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about simply:

`(!empty($_GET['is_test']) && $_GET['is_test'] === 'true' ? 1 : 0)`

**Edit:** Here you are checking the existence of the variable so you don't get a notice error.

Comment: @PathikVejani A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Answer (score 1):

The current answers are perfect. However, for maintenance and readability, you could easily make a parser class to complete these actions. Like this for example:

```
namespace Parser;

class Convert
{
    public static function StringToBoolean(
        $string
    ) {
        if(strpos('true', $string) || strpos('false', $string)) {
            return strpos('true', $string) ? true : false;
        }
        throw new Exception("$string is not true or false.");
    }
}
```

Then any time you want to use it, you can manually type the string or use a variable to convert.

```
echo (int) $example = Parser\Convert::StringToBoolean('true');   // 1
$stringBool = 'false';
echo (int) $example = Parser\Convert::StringToBoolean($stringBool);  // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @vp_arth  this was best option

```
echo intval($_GET['is_test'] === 'true') //gives 0,1 for false,true
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_GET['is_test']))
{
    return ($_GET['is_test']=="true") ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You can just use ternary option

Comment: both `'true'` and `'false'` give `1`. Need string compare.