# How to insert boolean value "false" as 0 with DB insert?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, insert, boolean

I receive data from a API request and it contains a value "true" or "false".

Before I've used PDO::PARAM_BOOL to bind the value and insert it into MySQL

Now I'm using Laravel and I want to know how I can insert this value as boolean value 1 or 0.

I've created a migration which contains

```
$table->boolean('businessorder');
```

I save the data in an array and insert it in my table:

```
$orderarray = [];

  foreach($csv as $data => $orderdata){
    $orderarray[] = [
    ...
    'businessorder' => $orderdata['is-business-order'],
    ...
    ];

  }
```

I receive the following error

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'false' for column 1
```

The error message also shows the data to insert in the database as "false" not as 0.

How can I make sure it will insert 0 or 1 instead of true or false

When I do

```
'businessorder' => (bool)$orderdata['is-business-order'],
```

It will set everything to 1 (because (bool)'false' is true)

Comment: You can add a simple check like: `$orderdata['is-business-order'] == 'true' ? 1 : 0`

Answer (score 1):

When you try to put the value of `$orderdata['is-business-order']` into the DB column, MySQL tries to put `true` or `false`.

But `true` or `false` cannot be stored in a boolean type column. So we can do something like the below code to get `1` or `0` instead of `true` or `false`.

```
businessorder' => ($orderdata['is-business-order']=='true'?1:0)
```

Comment: Kajan- you have to add some content in here to explain your code.

Comment: @staypuftman Sorry for that. I updated it. Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775294/parsing-a-string-into-a-boolean-value-in-php) you could do something like this:

```
'businessorder' => filter_var($orderdata['is-business-order'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```